# How to protect a USB from files being deleted by antivirus on any number of computers?

Tags: windows-10, usb, shortcuts, anti-virus

I have a work flash drive that I carry around a lot of places to give presentations. It connects to a wide range of desktops, laptops, projectors, and smartTVs. There is a common antivirus used in this country, Smadav (free version).

To make navigating my flash drive easier, I've made links from one folder to another. But anytime I do this, Smadav deletes them within a few seconds. This happens whether I link to a document in another folder (such as a powerpoint I created from scratch) or another folder.

The free version doesn't allow you to create exceptions or restore quarantined files. I also don't have the permissions (either administrative or social) to seek exceptions on every computer I plug into, even if it was technically possible.

Is there any way to protect a shortcut on a USB from the USB side, or do I have to resign myself to never having shortcuts on this USB?

Comment: upgrade to the paid version of Smadav maybe

Comment: @jsotola OP wrote `I also don't have the permissions (either administrative or social) to seek exceptions on every computer I plug into` so I don't think thats an option

Comment: are you saying that you are not using your own computer for presentations?  ... your post is unclear on this

Comment: @jsotola If it was OPs computer, they would have administrative and social permission to do whatever they want with it.

Comment: Try setting the readonly attribute on all files and directories.  Alternatively format the disk in NT format (may not be readable on Linux) and then set the readonly attribute.

Comment: Are you using your disk as read-only outside of your computer? You may set the entire disk to read-only using diskpart.

Comment: Or use a drive with read-only switch, e.g., https://www.amazon.com/s?k=usb+drive+with+write+protection